# GridGain network partitions with the Open Source version

Tags: gridgain

I've read on the GridGain website that Enterprise edition contains Network Segmentation protection, whereas the Open Source version doesn't.

In that case, what exactly would happen during a network partition with the Open Source version? Would it result in split brain?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes, in the open source edition the grid will be segmented and you will have to restart the segmented nodes in order for them to become a part of the grid again.

Comment: So the segmented nodes will still process transactions, or will they start to error? Also, would it be possible to roll your own protection via some kind of message from the grid when topology changes? Thanks for your help